# How to exit read only filesystem to get write permission in order to download a driver form Github?

Tags: linux, permissions, kali, root, git

I am trying to set up a 5 inch LCD on my Raspberry Pi 3. It runs Kali Linux, I'm on a no GUI boot and (automatically) logged in as root.

When I run the command (to download the drivers):

> git clone https://github.com/Elecrow-keen/Elecrow-LCD5.git

I get:

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'Elecrow-LCD5': Read Only Filesystem

I also don't have permission to create a new user (via `useradd`). How can I get write permissions?

P.S. I'm following these instructions with trouble at step 4: https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=HDMI_Interface_5_Inch_800x480_TFT_Display

Answer (score 2):

Try remounting root as read/write. Run `mount` to find the identifier and mount point, then run the following:

rpi ~# mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point `